# XSD error: The content is not valid. Expected is (annotation?)

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am trying to write an XSD. The following component is causing error, when I try to parse an XML using this XSD. The error message is

> The content is not valid. Expected is (annotation?)., Line 9

I tried deleting the `xs:annotation` portion, but with no luck.  I have both 'Job' and 'JobParameter' defined elsewhere. Can someone please help me?

```
<xs:complexType name='JobsType'>
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        A collection of Jobs for this component
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref='Job' minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='unbounded'>
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>
              A job element
            </xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name='JobParameters' type='JobParametersType' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>
                  A collection of job parameters
                </xs:documentation>
              </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name='JobParametersType'>
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        A collection of Actions for this component
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref='JobParameter' minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='unbounded'/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xs:element/@ref` to reference an element globally declared.

Use `xs:element/@name` to specify a name for an element locally declared as you have here.

### Use either `@ref` or `@name`. *You cannot use both concurrently*.

Here are the above corrections applied to your XSD.  Note that the `JobParameter` element likely would have a definition elsewhere defined that could referenced, but since you've not included it, I went ahead and just changed it too to a `@name` attribute.  You'll probably want to change that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:complexType name='JobsType'>
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        A collection of Jobs for this component
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name='Job' minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='unbounded'>
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>
              A job element
            </xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name='JobParameters' 
                        type='JobParametersType' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>
                  A collection of job parameters
                </xs:documentation>
              </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name='JobParametersType'>
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        A collection of Actions for this component
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name='JobParameter' 
                  minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='unbounded'/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I do have both 'Job' and 'JobParameter' defined elsewhere. Sorry I should've mentioned that in my post. I have added that now.

Comment: That's fine in the case of `JobParameter`, but in the case of `Job`, you cannot have both a global declaration referenced by `@ref` and a local declaration as a child of `xsd:element`.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks. Using 'name' will make that particular element name fixed as 'Job'. But I do not want that, I want that element name to be variable (instead of 'Job', it would be type of job like 'Painting', 'Sketching', 'Drawing' etc). Any idea how I can do that? Using 'ref' in 'JobParamtersType' did what I want, that's why I used the same in case of 'Job'.

Comment: Use `xsd:choice` to allow alternative elements in a content model.   Or, use `xsd:enumeration` for defining alternative simple type constants.

Comment: Or define Job as an abstract element, and define Painting, Sketching, Drawing, etc. as members of its substitution group.